# Are using a lot of new and delete operators time consuming in c++?

Tags: c++, memory-management, garbage-collection

Suppose we have a for loop. We create new objects and delete the objects inside it. C++ does not have any garbage collector, therefore new and delete objects is not time consuming a lot and does not have overhead like languages with memory management like C# and Java?

Comment: Don't use `new` and `delete`.

Comment: Why would you dynamically allocate memory using `new` and `delete` it within the same loop? Just create the objects locally on the stack. C++ isn't Java. You can create objects without using `new`.

Comment: Yes but I would like to know better about new and delete functionality in c++ with respect to other memory management languages  like Java or c# that have garbage collector. Why do not these operators have overheads?

Comment: Why do you think they have no overhead? Why do you think not having GC would mean creating and deleting objects wouldn’t be time consuming?

Comment: In C++, the new/delete does not have the overhead of a GC, such as a background thread, and potentially memory locking, and generational organization.  However, there is overhead with the bookkeeping of the global store (typically, the heap, but that's an implementation detail) to allocate, construct, destruct, and deallocate the objects.  Stack based objects do not have the allocate & deallocate overhead.  Is that the kind of "time consuming" you mean?

Comment: In the GC case, the overhead is almost entirely paid on the deallocation side and can vary based on the proportion of objects that live for varying amounts of time; in the `new`/`delete` case, the overhead is roughly balanced between allocation and deallocation, and will be very consistent throughout the program. The total overhead is significant for both approaches, but you "pay" for that overhead in very different ways. Both are valuable strategies for different workloads -- beware anyone who is too dogmatic about saying any one strategy is *always* better than another.

Comment: On many platforms, `new` and `delete` are more time consuming than declaring a local variable: 1) They call functions; 2) The `new` operator has to find a block of memory equal to or larger than the requested object; 3) Delete may append the variable to a memory pool.  With local variables, usually a stack pointer is incremented (very quick operation) or the a processor register is used.

Comment: On embedded systems, one object is declared statically and reused.  This prevents memory fragmentation which could be devastating on critical systems (such as aerospace or medical device applications).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you have a for loop that creates and deletes objects within it, that is the best case scenarios but while coding a real time project that will not be the case.

Especially if you have plans to translate the C++ to say example C#, where GC takes care of memory management, you will have to deal with the Pointers for Deleting objects first, you will also have to figure out the size of the garbage before deleting it.

Some important points:

- Avoid using Delete in CPP
- C# (.Net) allocation is very efficient but freeing memory gets quiet complex
- If the program does not rely on Intensive performance go for languages that support GC
- If your program contains a lot of short lived Objects go for GC
- Look up RAII (Resource acquisition is initialization) which does not force you to manage resources explicitly

Comment: What does "if your program contains a lot of long lived short objects go for GC" mean? GC is actually best in the case where most (>90%) of your objects are short lived, since the cost of collecting garbage is proportional to the number of *live* objects, not the number of objects that need to be collected.

Comment: @DanielPryden, You're right, thanks for pointing that out, I have edited it.

Comment: "Avoid using Delete in CPP" that is either completely wrong or you should explain it better. To me, you seem to be telling someone to never free dynamically allocated memory.